# "System files" on secondary drive take up 280GB

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

got several disks on this PC and on one, for some reason, "System files" in the "System & reserved" storage view take up 280GB without showing up anywhere in WinDirStat:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

There is also no swap, hibernation file or anything else stored here. Showing all hidden files in explorer doesn't change anything. I've tried to 'optimize' the drive without any changes.

Where are my 280GB? What is windows hiding from me?

**Update**
To answer the questions in the comments:

- I ran windirstat as admin
- This is the only partition on the disk (not that it matters, the reported 280GB are missing from F:)
- `vssadmin list shadowstorage` shows that only C: is used for shadow copying
- Indexing location is on C:
- "System protection" is only enabled on C: where it uses 3.8GB

Comment: Hi there - is it possible you have lots of rollback points?

Comment: please show the screenshot of diskmgmt.msc

Comment: how is your search working? if search results are slow and laggy, it could be that this is a massive indexing file that needs cleaning up.

Comment: Indexing or "Previous Versions". Either one of them or both together.

Comment: Could you post the output of `vssadmin list shadowstorage`?

Comment: Did you try running WinDirStat as administrator? If the 280GB of files are located in a folder that WinDirStat has no access to then as far as I know it cannot index them.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've edited to answer the questions. Still a mystery to me. Maybe something like bad blocks?

Comment: Maybe also try TreeSize Free. Also, did you reboot yet?

Answer (score 0):

The special "System Reserved" partition is typically created when you
install Windows on a clean disk.
This disk was probably previously used for installing
Windows, before it was converted to a data disk.

You screenshot is not clear, but if a "System Reserved" partition exists
on the disk, you may just delete it in Disk Management and extend the
data partition over its space.

If Disk Management will refuse to delete it, you may use a Linux boot USB
or some bootable
[Partition Management Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-partition-management-software.htm)
to delete the partition.
Once deleted, resizing the data partition is best done
using Disk Management.

---

If there is no "System Reserved" partition, then you have Windows
special files on the disk.

Try first in Explorer to right-click the disk, select properties,
and then Disk Clean-up.

Another possibility is System Restore files, accessible via
*Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings >
System Protection tab*, click your disk, then click Configure,
select Disable system protection and click OK.

Still another possibility is a page-file extension on the disk. Go to
*Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings >
Advanced tab*, click Settings under Performance, Advanced tab,
and click Change under Virtual memory.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He is asking about FILE-storage inside his F: drive. Not about an extra partition.

Comment: @Tonny: The answer is expanded to include more possibilities.